# PyDev - Project Suddenly Throwing "ImportError: cannot import name classobj"

Tags: python

As a Python novice I've built a large and sprawling project that while pretty ugly fulfils my requirements. But I just broke it.

I was trying to call various scripts held within separate folders, with something like

```
execfile("folder1/script1.py")
```

While didn't work. I dragged the file to another location to have a play around, and *I think* selected 'update references' or something similar. I might be wrong about that, being in a blind panic and all.

Now the entire project is broken, and I need a responsible adult to help me out of this mess.

```
Error processing line 1 of /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'module'

Remainder of file ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ben/Documents/workspace/FlightAnalytic/GetTracks/arrivalsLHR.py", line 2, in <module>
    from suds import null, WebFault
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/suds/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/suds/client.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/suds/sudsobject.py", line 25, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name classobj
```

This error is thrown whichever .py file I try to run.
Hoping someone can figure out what stupid thing I just did, and how to put it right.

Comment: You said you just move the file, so put it back to last location that works on there

Answer (score 1):

After taking a long walk I was able to see the problem. I'd created a new PyDev package within my project. My guess is all my scripts were pointing there - or somehow it had screwed up the wiring of the project.

Anyway, deleted it, fixed the problem.